# How to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.boots.models.TypeServiceModel' for property 'typeService'? (updated))

Tags: java

> Thank you all for your help. It turned out to be much easier than I
> thought. Was not very attentive. I passed a string and in the code
> there was a request to the server to get the object and add it to the
> declaration. I changed to id, since the request was made by id and
> changed the select typeService name to typeServiceId and everything
> worked out.

I needed to add a form to enter declarations on a site that is written in java. I added everything, but when I click create, an error like this comes out. I don't know what needs to be dropped to show everything.

```
Validation failed for object='advertForm'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: 
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'advertForm' on field 'typeService': rejected value 
[TypeServiceModel(id=28, name=Авто-каток, виброкатки, removedDate=null, removedDateStr=)]; 
codes [typeMismatch.advertForm.typeService,typeMismatch.typeService,typeMismatch.com.boots.models.
TypeServiceModel,typeMismatch]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
[advertForm.typeService,typeService]; arguments []; default message [typeService]];
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required 
type 'com.boots.models.TypeServiceModel' for property 'typeService'; nested exception is  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required       
type 'com.boots.models.TypeServiceModel' for property 'typeService': no matching editors or 
conversion strategy found]
```

Here is the form itself

```
<form:form role="form" modelAttribute="advertForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/advert/save" method="post">
<div class="form-group row">
   <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Тип</label>
       <div class="col-lg-9">
             <select name="typeService" id="typeService" class="form-control">
                   <option value="Тип транспорта">Тип транспорта</option>
                       <c:forEach items="${typeService}" var="type">
                            <option id="${type}" name="${type}" value="${type}">${type.name}</option>
                       </c:forEach>
               </select>
           </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML works with Strings. Spring needs a way to convert Strings to the type that you declare in your form backing object. As Spring does not know about `TypeServiceModel`, this will not be automatic. You will need to implement a custom converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.UUID;

@Component
public class StringToTypeServiceModelConverter implements Converter<String, TypeServiceModel> {
    @Override
    public TypeServiceModel convert(String s) {
        return ... // do conversion here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see any example of a converter?

Answer (score 0):

1. Easy way: change the value of the option with a string instead of type such as

   value="${type.uniqueTypeStringValue}
   and change the signature of your Java method to get a String parameter instead of a TypeServiceModel. Then you can do the logic to convert that unique string to a type parameter object if you have the required information somewhere
2. Add a Jackson library (or dependency if using Maven) and configure it to do the automatic conversion between types. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization and https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: The problem is that I have been doing this project for only 3 days. And I don't fully understand how java works

Comment: Well JavaScript  is a weakly typed language and it's more relaxed in syntax and rules. But Java is a  strongly typed language which means that  the type of a variable is checked at compile-time. So your program won't work until you convert that string (posted from the frontend to the backend) to the type that Java wants (TypeServiceModel). To do that conversion easily, there are some Java libraries as I mentioned above.

Comment: OK thank you very much. I will explore these libraries